# Unable to get the handlebar data into template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data, mustache

I am learning ember.js through the [official documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/displaying-model-data/) and am having the following html page that contains mustache template:

```
 <section id="main">
      <ul id="todo-list">
        {{#each controller}}
        <li {{bindAttr class="isCompleted:completed"}}>
          <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
          <label>{{title}}</label><button class="destroy"></button>
        </li>
        {{/each}}
      </ul>

      <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-all">
    </section>
```

However, the problem is that the browser displays the data as:

```
{{#each controller}}
  {{title}}
{{/each}}
```

without rendering the seed data supplied into the template.
I am having the following javascript declarations just before the end of body tag:

```
  <script src="js/libs/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-data.js"></script>

  <script src="js/libs/application.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/router.js"></script>
  <script src="js/models/store.js"></script>
  <script src="js/models/todo.js"></script>
```

The page loads without any error reported by firebug. Please let me know what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are missing something fundamental - the handlebars script tag around your 'template', the `data-template-name` should be named depending on the route your are in, I've used here `application` only for the sake of the example. On the official guides you mentioned if you enable the html panel in embedded jsbin you will see what I mean, right under the `body` tag is the wrapping script tag named `todos`.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
 <section id="main">
  <ul id="todo-list">
    {{#each controller}}
    <li {{bindAttr class="isCompleted:completed"}}>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
      <label>{{title}}</label><button class="destroy"></button>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>

  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-all">
</section>
</script>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: many thanks, I've been following the getting started user guide and there was no such mention of an enclosing script tag.